# react create-app typescript compilerOptions file like angular

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm just playing around with react typescript

and I'm wondering if its possible to have a dedicate

file with the compiler options like tsconfig.json in angular.

For instance how can set

```
"strict": true,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `tsconfig.json` is specific to TypeScript, not Angular. When you generate a new TypeScript project using `create-react-app <app-name> --typescript`, a `tsconfig.json` file will be generated too.

Comment: Thanks I've missed it :(